# How to find the regularization parameter in logistic regression in python scikit-learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

In scikit-learn, the C is the inverse of regularization strength ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)). I have manually computed three training with the same parameters and conditions except I am using three different C's (i.e. 0.1, 1.0, and 10.0). I compared the F-score in the validation set, and identify the "best" C. However, someone told me this is wrong as I am not supposed to use the validation set to optimize C. How should I pick the right C? And what justification I have if I am to choose the default C (= 1.0) from scikit-learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I pick the right C?

You are supposed to have three-folded dataset: training, validation and testing. You train on train, set hyperparameters on validation and finally evaluate on test. In particular, when data is small you can do this with k-fold CV fashion, where you first employ CV for train-test splits, and then yet another one inside, which splits train further to actual train and validation.

> And what justification I have if I am to choose the default C (= 1.0) from scikit-learn?

There is no justification besides putting an arbitrary prior on weights (thus any other value would be equally justified).

Comment: In the situation where the C is chosen based on the performance of the test set, is it an example of overfitting? I am trying to understand why it is a bad idea to do so.

Comment: it is not **example** of overfitting, it is example of **invalid estimator**, simply you cannot trust a model selected in such a way. It is related to the overfitting in this sense that it can lead to it, but the problem is deeper - simply if you use data to both making **any** decisions about the model, and also its evaluation - the evaluation is **biased** and consequently - useless.